# Use js packages in BigQuery UDF

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I was trying to create a BigQuery UDF which requires an external npm package.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION tempfn(message STRING)
RETURNS STRING 
  LANGUAGE js AS """
  var tesfn = require('js-123');
  return tesfn(message)
""";  
SELECT tempfn("Hello") as test;
```

It gives me an error

> ReferenceError: require is not defined at tempfn(STRING) line 2,
>   columns 15-16

Is there a way that I can use these packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't load npm packages using `require` from JavaScript UDFs. You can, however, load external libraries from GCS, as [outlined in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#including-external-libraries). The example that the documentation gives is,

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION myFunc(a FLOAT64, b STRING)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js AS
"""
    // Assumes 'doInterestingStuff' is defined in one of the library files.
    return doInterestingStuff(a, b);
"""
OPTIONS (
  library="gs://my-bucket/path/to/lib1.js",
  library=["gs://my-bucket/path/to/lib2.js", "gs://my-bucket/path/to/lib3.js"]
);

SELECT myFunc(3.14, 'foo');
```

Here the assumption is that you have files with these names in Cloud Storage, and that one of them defines `doInterestingStuff`.